# Add checked attribute to closest checkbox within TR

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the Quantity text input is changed (up/down), I'd like the checkboxes on that same TR line to then get the 'checked' attribute.

**My attempt so far:**
I suspect it's along these lines with the use of .closest but just have quite got it yet, here is my go so far:

```
function addCheck() {
$('table.table-bordered input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
    // get current row
    parent = $(this).closest('tr');
    // in row find input and add the value 
    $('#option-value-417').attr( 'checked', 'checked' );
});
}
```

The text input then has the function added, ready:

```
onchange="addCheck();"
```

At the moment I have hard coded the checkbox ID number.

Website URL: http://rlpetproducts2.designlocker.co.uk/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=251

[image]

Comment: Once you have that figured out remember to add check for 0 quantity that will uncheck the checkbox, as well as unchecking the checkbox will set quantity to 0, without circular references. Or look it [observables](https://github.com/erosb/jquery.observable) plugin.

Comment: Speaking of observables, earlier I was fooling around with knockoutjs, should you be interested in learning that, these types of forms could be very easily maintained this way. https://jsfiddle.net/5ctgdLmx/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try the following jquery snippet :**

```
 $('input[type="text"]').on('change',function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr( 'checked', 'checked' );
    });
```

OR

```
 $('input[type="text"]').on('change',function(){
    $(this).closest('input[type="checkbox"]').attr( 'checked', 'checked' );
    });
```

Comment: This first snippet worked, however for some reason you must click the UP/DOWN arrow twice before it will tick the checkbox.

Comment: @JordanC26 : that's because you've still retained the `addCheck()` function in your code, directly put the above snippet in your `$(document).ready()` block and it should work perfectly, since you are still using the `addCheck()`, you are having to click twice for the change to be detected, my snippet takes care of detecting the change in the input value.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have a class `jordan` in the both of the inputs so you can use it to attach the event to them :

```
$('body').on('change', '.jordan', function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
})
```

Hope this helps.